# How to use active_enum enumarate in an HTML select element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-enum

I'm using the `active_enum` gem in my Rails 4 application. https://github.com/adzap/active_enum

```
gem 'active_enum'
```

In my model, I have an enumerate:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  enumerate :participant_type do
    value 0 => 'Juniors'
    value 1 => 'Senior'
    value 2 => 'Administration'
  end
end
```

How can I use these values in a form select element?

I've tried the following but I get a runtime error:

```
= f.select :participant_type, Loan.participant_type

undefined method `participant_type' for #<Class:0x007f8803581050>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Participant type as a separate class that extends ActiveEnum::Base and try `.to_select` method.

```
= f.select :participant_type, ParticipantType.to_select, required: true
```

If it is Active Record Enum, try the below:

It is a plural `participant_types` as mentioned in the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

```
= f.select :participant_type, Meeting.participant_types, required: true
```

Comment: No, that's for baked in ActiveRecord::Enum's. I'm not using those in this case. I'm using `active_enum` a completely separate gem. :)

Comment: there are few options - Make a separate class and use to_select, or use the form helpers as mentioned here https://github.com/adzap/active_enum#form-helpers